# Why don't PHP and Javascript's timestamps match?

Tags: php, javascript, date

If I do

`alert(new Date(1313690400000))`

returns: `Thu Aug 18 2011 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)`

however, PHP

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1313690400000);`

returns: `1951-12-14 05:50:24`

Comment: It'll help you to get answers down the road if you'll accept an answer by clicking the check mark beside one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

JavaScript uses milliseconds as a timestamp, whereas PHP uses seconds. As a result, you get very different dates, as it is off by a factor 1000.

So remove three zeroes at the PHP side:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1313690400);
```

Answer (score 6):

Javascript Date is milliseconds since Epoch, whereas PHP date uses unix timestamp which is in seconds.

So to get the same date in php, divide by 1000 first

Answer (score 5):

PHP's date/time functions use the number of seconds since the epoch, while Javascript uses the number of milliseconds.  In your php func:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', 1313690400000 / 1000);
```