# unable to get date and time from timestamp in php?

Tags: php

I have written the following code:

```
$timestamp = "1483625713000";
$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
$time = date('Gi.s', $timestamp);
```

but the output is not coming as expected:
My outputs:

```
echo $date  //   23-03-48984
echo $time  //   2136.40
```

Comment: How did you generate that timestamp? If you cut off the last 3 0s, it gives a proper timestamp (2017-01-05 09:15:13).

Comment: but thatsolution is not working for me

Comment: @anyber u r right maybe i have to check its generation.

Comment: Note that the unix timestamp can only contain a 32-bit integer. You're overflowing it now, which causes all kinds of chaos. https://3v4l.org/JCIGM

Comment: I'm guessing you've got this timestamp from JavaScript? There's a difference, where PHP uses seconds, and JS uses milliseconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114603/why-dont-php-and-javascripts-timestamps-match

Comment: also consider for new users how you define `as expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got milliseconds in that timestamp. Try this:

```
$timestamp = 1483625713000 / 1000;
$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
$time = date('Gi.s', $timestamp);

var_dump($date);
var_dump($time);
```

Outputs

```
string(10) "05-01-2017"
string(7) "1415.13"
```